# Will a Charged TM still give a legacy Mewtwo shadow ball?

Tags: pokemon-go

I have a rather complicated question that could easily be misinterpreted so please read this carefully.

I have a Mewtwo that I got during an EX raid in early 2018.  Back then Shadow Ball was a possible charge move for Mewtwo.  Sadly the Mewtwo I got did not have Shadow Ball as it's charge move.  I only had a few Charged TMs at the time so I tried to get Shadow Ball but failed.  I stopped playing for a while and just this month, when I started playing again, I read that Shadow Ball was removed from Mewtwo sometime in mid to late 2018.  My question is....

Since my Mewtwo was captured back when Shadow Ball was a valid charge move, does it still have the potential to have Shadow Ball if I use a Charge TM on it?  Or when Niantic removed Shadow Ball as a charge move do they block it on all Mewtwo, including a legacy Mewtwo?

Answer (score 10):

In Pokémon GO, TMs can only grant a Pokémon moves that are currently available. So-called 'legacy' moves that used to be available but are no longer available therefore cannot be TM'd onto a Pokémon, regardless of when the Pokémon was captured.

In addition, unlocking second Charge Moves does NOT allow special moves or legacy moves to be obtained (as of Jan 2019).

As a result, using a Charge TM will grant one of the following: Psychic, Focus Blast, Ice Beam, Thunderbolt, or Flamethrower (as of Jan 2019).

Answer (score 4):

Andrew's answer is still accurate that using a Charged TM will not give Mewtwo Shadow Ball. However, with the release of new [Elite Charged TMs](https://pokemongohub.net/post/guide/elite-charged-tm-and-elite-fast-tm-in-pokemon-go/), you can now teach Pokemon legacy moves (including previous community day moves for the respective Pokemon)!

Elite Charged TMs are hard to come by. So far, the only two known ways to obtain one are:

- Reach Rank 7 in the Battle Leagues
- Purchase boxes during certain times (at the time of writing, Abra community day is the only day where these have appeared)

Below is a screenshot of me using an Elite Charged TM, and was given the option to teach Mewtwo Shadow Ball

[image: Mewtwo learning shadow ball]